# html multiple <ol> lists on one page with different start

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple  lists on one page with different start properties. When I add new element to the list I have to change all start elements (increment by one). How to do it in an intelligent way, for instance using javascript?
I was trying to use javascript function with:
`document.getElementById("ol.2019").start = "10";`

but I did not managed to make it work.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was provided by ActiveCodex:

```
<script>  
  $( document ).ready(function() {
  var isFirst = true, numLi = 1;
  $('ol').each(function() {
    var list = $(this);
    list.attr("start", numLi);
    numLi = numLi + list.find("li").length;
  });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be easier to use the `start` attribute on your list, no need for JS, more [information here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_ol_start.asp).

```html
<ol>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ol>


<ol start="10">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ol>


<ol start="543">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I was doing up to now. This way, every time a new entry arrives, I have to change value of the start attribute in about 20 lists manually. I'm trying to simplify it.

Comment: Hi. Then I would suggest you to use `counter-increment` - [ https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/counter-increment/ ]

Comment: Hm... I'm not familiar with jQuery. I have:
`<script>
  var isFirst = true, numLi = 1;
  $('ol').each(function() {
      console.log( $(this).children('li').size() );
 var list = $(this);
 list.attr("start", numLi);
 numLi = numLi + list.find("li").length;
    }); 
  </script>`
But the Firefox console tells me:
ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: `counter-increment` is pure CSS

Comment: For you `$` error, make sure jQuery is included on your site. If you do have it included, perhaps your code is running before jQuery is ready. Wrap the entire code with `document.ready` [ https://api.jquery.com/ready/ ]

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you ActiveCodex! I'll copy the whole code as a solution for future generations:-) Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. If this comment/answer or any other one solved your issue, please upvote/mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem you are trying to use a getElementById as it could be use to find a selector, you should look for an ID, not for a tag with a class. Also you can try not using classes starting with a number:

```
("ol.2019")
```

so change your classes with something like class="year_2019"

hope this will help

Comment: Hm. It does not work... Lets say I have javascript function 
`  <script>
    document.onload = function(){
 var start2019=10;
 document.getElementById("ol.y2019").start = start2019;
    }; 
  </script>
` 
and then in the body I do:
`<ol.y2019>`
my list does not even have number anymore, it has bullet points.

Comment: I think there is a bit of confusion here: check out [this getElementById reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp). You have to define an `<ol id="y2019">` and use `document.getElementById("y2019")`. Keep in mind that should be only one ID in the DOM so don't use the same ID more than one time, if you cannot you have to make it unique and find a way to get this element by that ID. Or you can try with other approches. So: `<script> document.onload = function(){ document.getElementById("y2019").start = 10; }; </script>  ...  <ol id="y2019"><li></li></ol>`